# Firing change() event for input checkboxes doesn't trigger all event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

We have around twenty input checkboxes, and they're divided into six groups using CSS classes. We added an event handler for the change event on each of the six classes, and then we added a final event handler for the change event on the input element itself. It looks like this:

(HTML)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" class="A"> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" class="A"> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" class="B"> 3
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" class="B"> 4
// ...
// checkboxes for classes C, D, E
// ...
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" class="F"> 20
```

(jQuery)

```
$('.A').change(function() {
    // doesn't get called
});

$('.B').change(function() {
    // doesn't get called
});

$('.C').change(function() {
    // doesn't get called
});

$('.D').change(function() {
    // doesn't get called
});

$('.E').change(function() {
    // doesn't get called
});

$('.F').change(function() {
    // doesn't get called
});

$('input[name="cbox"]').change(function() {
    // this one gets called
});

$('input[name="cbox"]').change();
```

When I finally call `$('input[name="cbox"]').change()`, the only event handler that gets called is the last one, i.e.

```
$('input[name="cbox"]').change(function() {
    // this one gets called
});
```

All the other event handlers that I added (for classes A, B, C, D, E and F) don't get called. Why is this? Shouldn't `$('input[name="cbox"]').change()` trigger all of the event handlers, and not just the one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('input.A').change(function(event) {
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: That's interesting - why do you think adding input should make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dm4vLku/)

I dont know why its not working, Working to me i posted fiddle for sandbox

```js
let classnamelist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','y',]
for(let i = 0; i<classnamelist.length; i++){
let el = $('<input>').attr({
'type':'checkbox',
'name':'cbox'
}).addClass(classnamelist[i]);

$('body').append(el);

$('.'+classnamelist[i]).change(function(){
alert($(this).is(':checked'))
})
}
$('input[name=cbox]').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're adding the checkboxes dynamically you should try :

```
$(document).on('change', '.A', function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Hm, we're not adding the check boxes dynamically. They're hardcoded in the HTML as shown in my question.